# Marionette.js - hijacking CompositeView functions to create streaming pagination

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am creating a streaming paginated list of views. We start the app with an empty collection and add items to the collection at regular intervals. When the size of the collection passes a page_size attribute then the rest of the models should not get rendered, but the compositeView should add page numbers to click on.

I am planning on creating a render function for my compositeView that only renders items based on the current page# and page size by have a function in my collection that returns a list of models like this:

```
get_page_results: function(page_number){
    var all_models = this.models;

    var models_start = page_number * this.page_size;
    var models_end = models_start + this.page_size;

    //return array of results for that page
    return all_models.slice(models_start,models_end);
}
```

My question is, **should I even be using Marionette's composite view for this?** It seems like im overwriting most of the functionality of Marionette's collectionView to get what I want.

Every time the number of items in my collection changes two things need to be updated:

- The itemViews in the collection view
- The page numbers at the bottom of the composite view

Comment: If you can naturally do it with the collection view, then that would be better. But if you have to "hack" it, you may just need to create something new out of more basic pieces. One thing to keep in mind, is you may be able to change the CompositeView's actual "collection" to contain just the elements you want on the page. You also just might create serveral CompositeViews - one for each page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My strong recommendation is not to do this in the view layer. You're going to add a ton of code to your views, and you're going to end up duplicating a lot of this code between multiple views (one for displaying the data, one for page list and counts, one for ...).

Instead, use a decorator pattern to build a collection that knows how to handle this. I do this for filtering, sorting and paging data, and it works very well.

For example, here's how I set up filtering (running in a JSFdiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/derickbailey/vm7wK/)

```
function FilteredCollection(original){
    var filtered = Object.create(original);

    filtered.filter = function(criteria){
        var items;
        if (criteria){
            items = original.where(criteria);
        } else {
            items = original.models;
        }
        filtered.reset(items);
    };        

    return filtered;
}

var stuff = new Backbone.Collection();

var filtered = FilteredCollection(stuff);
var view = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.collection.on("reset", this.render, this);
    },

    render: function(){
        var result = this.collection.map(function(item){ return item.get("foo"); });
        this.$el.html(result.join(","));
    }
});
```

In your case, you won't be doing filtering like this... but the idea for paging and streaming would be the same.

You would track what page # you are on in your "PagingCollection", and then when your original collection is reset or has new data added to it, the PagingCollection functions would re-calculate which data needs to be in the final pagedCollection instance, and reset that collection with the data you need.

Something like this (though this is untested and incomplete. you'll need to fill in some detail and flesh it out for your app's needs)

```
function PagingCollection(original){
    var paged = Object.create(original);
    paged.currentPage = 0;
    paged.totalPages = 0;
    paged.pageSize = 0;

    paged.setPageSize = function(size){
      paged.pageSize = size;
    };

    original.on("reset", function(){
      paged.currentPage = 0;
      paged.totalPages = original.length / paged.pageSize;
      // get the models you need from "original" and then
      // call paged.reset(models) with that list
    });

    original.on("add", function(){
      paged.currentPage = 0;
      paged.totalPages = original.length / paged.pageSize;
      // get the models you need from "original" and then
      // call paged.reset(models) with that list
    });

    return paged;
}
```

Once you have the collection decorated with the paging info, you pass the paged collection to your CollectionView or CompositeView instance. These will properly render the models that are found in the collection that you pass to it.

Regarding CollectionView vs CompositeView ... a CompositeView is a CollectionView (it extends directly from it) that allows you to render a model / template around the collection. That's the majority difference... they both deal with collections, and render a list of views from that collection.

Answer (score 0):

We have built a set of mixins for `bakcbone.marionette` that you may find usefull (https://github.com/g00fy-/marionette.generic/)

You could use PaginatedMixin, that allows a Backbone collection to be paginated + a PrefetchMixin, so you don't have to pass a prefetched collection to a view.

the only code you would have to do is:

```
YourListView = Generic.ListView.mixin(PaginatedMixin,LoadingMixin,PrefetchMixin).extend({
    paginateBy:10,
    template:"#your-list-template",
    itemViewOptions:{template:"#your-itemview-template"},
    fetchPage:function(page){
        this.page = page;
        return this.collection.refetch({data:{page:page}}); // your code here
    },
    hasNextPage:function(){
      return true; // your code here
    },
});
```

For a working example see https://github.com/g00fy-/stack.reader/blob/master/js/views.js